# Function problems program

Tags: python, file, tkinter, crash

I wrote a program that makes a list 
But when the content of the imported files is high 
The program is off(**crash**) 
This is the code I wrote

---

In this photo, a file with low content is used

### [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozJIg.png)

This photo uses a file with a lot of content

### [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXtjD.png)

**[file zip](https://github.com/OKHTAY2001/zz2f/)**

```
def btn_start():
    try:
        if open_file1_text and open_file2_text :
            file_1 = open(open_file1_text.get(), 'r')
            file_2 = open(open_file2_text.get(), 'r')
            lines_1 = file_1.readlines()
            lines_2 = file_2.readlines()
            global text
            text = ("")
            demo_text_box.delete(1.0,'end')
            demo_text_box_a.delete(1.0,'end')
            demo_text_box_a.insert(INSERT,start_text_demo )
            for pline in lines_2:
                for uline in lines_1:
                    demo_text_box.insert(INSERT,uline.rstrip('\n') + separator_text_.get() + pline)
                    text += (uline.rstrip('\n') + separator_text_.get() + pline)

            file_1.close()
            file_2.close()
    except FileNotFoundError :
        demo_text_box.delete(1.0,'end')
        demo_text_box_a.delete(1.0,'end')
        demo_text_box_a.insert(INSERT,File_Not_Found_Error )
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us the error you're getting?

Comment: The program works properly
But the more content there is, the more the program doesn't work

Comment: What does "content is high" mean? I've successfully used a text widget with many thousands of lines.

Comment: @vlad0024 Your nested `for pline ... for uline ...` looks bad. Add a `print(uline)` to verify it's still looping. What do you want to accomplish here?

Comment: I put the program in GitHub
You can test

https://github.com/OKHTAY2001/zz2f

Answer (score 0):

Your code has another problem: if `file_2` is not found, then `file_1` will be left open, which may be bad (you want to close files as soon as you no longer need them).

You can solve this with `with` statements, which automatically close your files even when an exception occurs.

As for your memory problem, I guess `text` does not fit in memory, so you may want writing its content to another file.

```
def btn_start(open_file1_text, open_file2_text):
    if not (open_file1_text and open_file2_text):
        return

    try:
        with open(open_file1_text.get(), 'r') as file_1:
            lines_1 = file_1.readlines()
            with open(open_file1_text.get(), 'r') as file_2:
                lines_2 = file_2.readlines()
                demo_text_box.delete(1.0, 'end')
                demo_text_box_a.delete(1.0, 'end')
                demo_text_box_a.insert(INSERT, start_text_demo)

                with open('text.txt', 'w') as text_file:
                    for pline in lines_2:
                        for uline in lines_1:
                            demo_text_box.insert(INSERT,uline.rstrip('\n') + separator_text_.get() + pline)
                            text_file.write(uline.rstrip('\n') + separator_text_.get() + pline)
    except FileNotFoundError :
        demo_text_box.delete(1.0,'end')
        demo_text_box_a.delete(1.0,'end')
        demo_text_box_a.insert(INSERT,File_Not_Found_Error )
```

If the files themselves do not fit in memory (meaning you cannot call `file.readlines()`), 
you can also read them at each iteration of the loop:

```
with open('text.txt', 'w') as text_file:
    with open(open_file1_text.get(), 'r') as file_2:
        for pline in file_2:
            with open(open_file1_text.get(), 'r') as file_1:
                for uline in file_1:
                    demo_text_box.insert(INSERT,uline.rstrip('\n') + separator_text_.get() + pline)
                    text_file.write(uline.rstrip('\n') + separator_text_.get() + pline)
```

Comment: But the more content there is in the file, the more it doesn't work